# What to do with tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do people find the current tag system working? Does it help in finding questions?

Some of our tags seem to have relatively large scope (halacha, minhag, history, hashkafa, and parshanut seem to contain most questions that would come up here).

Some tags seem synonymous (parshanus and tanach)

Considering that we only have five maximum tags per question, should we try to re-organize the tagging system?

Comment: Note that some efforts at so doing are already here at Meta, tagged [meta-tag:specific-tag] (also [meta-tag:tags]).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question: yes. I have found the tags to consistently make it easier to find questions of a certain type, or individual ones, than searching through them all one by one. They are also more efficient than Googling a given term would be without tags since they offer meta information that is not necessarily named in the text of the question or its answers, such as the question's type and general area of subject matter.

I imagine improvements to the efficiency of the tagging system could still be made, but some of the synonymous tags like the pair you mentioned are valuable in my opinion. They, like actual synonyms, offer distinctions in classification beyond what either of them would offer alone. For example, a question on the "literary stratum" about specific words of Tana"ch constitutes a question in [parshanut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshanut) while one regarding the chronological identification of an individual whose name appears in two different books does not.